# InvalidConfirmationCode not Found exception in laravel 5

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to send a verfication link after the user completes registration in my web app. I have successfully sent an email to the user but when I click the link in the email I get this error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InvalidConfirmationCodeException' not found
```

This is my Controller

```
 public function confirm($code)
    {
        if( ! $code)
        {
            throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
        }

        $user = User::whereConfirmationCode($code)->first();

        if (!$user)
        {
            throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
        }

        $user->confirmed = 1;
        $user->confirmation_code = null;
        $user->save();

        Flash::message('You have successfully verified your account.');

        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
```

What is the possible error? please help

Comment: since you are throwing this exception,  `throw new InvalidConfirmationCodeException` means the confirmation code does not exists in users table. Its possible the confirmation code was not inserted in the table.

Comment: @Digitlimit the class is not found, so it has nothing to do with whether the code is in the table or not

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo its true.. didn't notice class not found in the error message.

Comment: @Sid you need to include `use InvalidConfirmationCodeException` in your controller. Also ensure you have created this custom exception exists.

Comment: I found the solution for it. thankyout@Digitlimit, @jedrzej.kurylo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **InvalidConfirmationCodeException** is probably in another namespace than **App\Http\Controllers**, that's why it can't be found. Use namespaced class name

```
throw new \Your\Exceptions\Namespace\InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
```

or import the exception class using **use** statement at the top of your controller file:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Your\Exceptions\Namespace\InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
```